# Failure to boot into Windows 10 using rEFInd boot manger while triple booting Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: windows-10, macos, ubuntu, refind

I'm attempting to triple boot my Macbook from an external SSD. I first started with installing Windows 10 on the external SSD following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IhW722IMwE. Following that I followed this tutorial to install Ubuntu on the second partition [here](https://florisvanbreugel.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/installing-ubuntu-on-an-external-ssd-drive-on-a-macbook/). I was able to boot into both Windows 10 and then into Ubuntu using reFInd. However, now I can't boot into Windows 10 and I keep getting the error "BlInitializelLibrary failed 0xc00000bb". When I searched this error I end up at a website [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323461/triple-boot-macos-high-sierra-linux-mint-and-windows-with-refind). This does not resolve the issue for me though.

What I've tired since is creating a folder in Ubuntu under "/boot/efi/EFI/Windows" and then mounting that partition to that folder. In the folder "/boot/efi/EFI/" I only had "APPLE, refind, tools, ubuntu" before.

I have also followed the steps at these links as well [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1221917/bootloaders-not-showing-up-in-uefi).

While in Ubuntu if I type efibootmgr -v into terminal I get,

> BootCurrent: 0000
> Timeout: 2 seconds
> BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0080,0081,0082
> Boot0000* ubuntu  HD(1,GPT,2a4cd9af-2573-486d........)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
> Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,2a3cd9af-2573-.....)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
> Boot0002* Windows  HD(7,GPT,0000000-0000-0000-0000,0x0,0x1)/File(\EFI\Windows\grubx64.efi)
> Boot0080* Mac OS x PciRoot(0x0).....
> .....

I'm not sure but this may be part of the issue? I'm just not sure.

If possible I could reformat the windows partition and reinstall but I wouldn't know how to follow up to get it to boot.

Comment: As a follow up, I looked into the guide [here](https://superuser.com/questions/986134/tried-triple-boot-on-mbp-broke-windows?rq=1) and when I went through and ran "mkdir /Volumes/ESP", "sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP" I then see that there is nothing in the EFI/Windows folder.

Comment: Under /Volumes in MacOS I do see Macintosh HD and WinToUSB which WinToUSB is the SSD. Going into WinToUSB I see the files for Windows. I then cd to Boot and then to EFI and then I see the bootmgr.efi. Do I need to relocate this to the bootloader?

Comment: Your mistake is having a MacBook. You should break it with a hammer and buy a real laptop. Repairing these things manually seems like a problem. Try repairing Windows from the windows usb and after that use Ubuntu Boot repair from an Ubuntu Live USB. Using Ubuntu repair will solve your problem after reinstallstion. I will post the link in a moment.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Ubuntu-20-04-not-boot-properly/answer/Albert-Mikolasov

Answer (score 0):

Soooo much attempts to fix this!

I finally found a solution and it comes from the author of both gdisk and rEFInd though this StackExchange [post](https://superuser.com/questions/986134/tried-triple-boot-on-mbp-broke-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1). Rod explained to be in MacOS and `mkdir /Volumes/ESP` to be able to access the ESP volumes. Then `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP`. Once there make sure you're in EFI-mode and not BIOS. The thing that fixed everything though was the next step of using `gdisk`. To do this you type `gdisk /dev/disk0`, the solution I found to work for me though was to also perform this on disk2 but for you maybe also disk1. Possibly there is a way to check what disk to use beforehand but unknown to me. Then just follow the rest of the steps.